# How to disable keyboard showing when EditText focused?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

There is need to open keyboard attached to one view and delegate key events to edittext, but there is no need to attach keyboard to EditText when it is focused. I tried with this code:

**in manifest:**

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

**code:**

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) rootView.getContext()
                                   .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keycode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        switch (keyEvent.getAction()){
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
                editText.onKeyUp(keycode, keyEvent);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                editText.onKeyDown(keycode, keyEvent);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

All is going ok (keyboard is showing), but when edittext gains focus - all logic ruined (keybord reshowed on edittext);

```
editext.requestFocus();
```

Focus in edit text needed to handle selection and other things that depends on focus.

Any help is important for me, thank you;

**UPDATE:**
There is no need to hide keyboard, desired steps:

1. Keyboard opened and attached to some view
2. Edit text gets focus, but keyboard doesn't atached to it

Answer (score 2):

If this is an activity you are working with you can use the following line in the manifest to hide the keyboard on creation.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function :

```
/* Hides keyboard, if diaplayed */
public void hideKeyboard(){
    View currentFocus = MainAcitivty.this.getCurrentFocus();    // Change the name according to your activity's name.
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(currentFocus != null){
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.getWindowToken(),0);
        currentFocus.clearFocus();
    }
}
```

And Call the above function from where ever you want to hide keyboard.

Hope this helps...